# what does the Lookup field mean in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am quite new to SharePoint,sometimes when I read book or blog, I come across "two lists in SharePoint ,with one list performing a lookup on the other list.".What does the lookup mean here , can anyone point me some tutorial to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog you read meant "Lookup Column". It is a mechanism to refer columns in one list from abother list. There are some nice improvements in Sharepoint 2010 around this area. Please check following video for more information.

http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/sharepoint-2010-list-enhancements-and-customizations/10txq33y1